# What connector do I need to match my existing test leads?

Tags: identification, plug

I'm building a tester and want to use existing test leads from my multimeter which has these kinds of connectors.

[image]

The testing probes use these plugs.

[image]

What kind of connector (or is it a "plug"?) do I need to buy to accept my existing test probes?

(And just how badly am I mangling the terminology here?)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

These are generally standard 4mm banana connectors. The specific ones you show are shrouded ones. They need to be shrouded in order for your multimeter to meet its safety specs. For the male connectors, standard connectors can be used in jacks designed to take shrouded ones. In the other direction, this is not the case - a shrouded plug cannot go into a unshrouded jack (because the shroud will be in the way)

Comment: I know them under shrouded, not shielded.

Comment: Yeah, mixup on my part. Fixed.

Comment: Well I did ask about my terminology. :)  So I need 2 4mm shrouded banana jacks.

Comment: @Tut I alwys get these mixed up...

Comment: They are sometimes called **sheathed** rather than shrouded.